# How to expand Kubernetes node instance profiles created by kops?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

I'm running a Kubernetes cluster on AWS, managed with kops. Now I want to run external-dns, which requires additional permissions in the nodes instance role. My question is: what is the best way to make these changes?

I *could* edit the role manually in AWS, but I want to automate my setup. I *could* also edit the role through the API (using the CLI, Cloudformation, Terraform, etc), but then I have a two-phase setup which seems fragmented and inelegant. Ideally I'd want to tell kops about my additional needs, and have it manage those with the ones it manages itself. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/iam_roles.md#adding-additional-policies

Comment: Interesting. I was looking for that exact thing, but missed it I guess. Still - now I have to go with the imperative `kops edit` and `kops update`. Any way I can keep the cluster spec in a git repo?

Comment: You could always check in portions of the S3 bucket to git, as that's where it's actually storing this information. I haven't tried it, but I'd imagine you could simply bring up a new cluster, upload the saved data back to S3, then do a rolling update.